# Permanently alter touchpad sensitivity settings

Tags: touchpad, configuration, xinput

My ultimate goal is to reduce the sensitivity of my synaptics touchpad. Right now, when I type something, random tap events (e.g. mouseclicks) occur. In order to do so I would like to permanently store configuration values for the touchpad as would be listed by running:

```
xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"
```

I tried creating a new conf file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99synaptics-sensitivity` as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "synaptics-sensitivity"
        MatchProduct "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"
        # here add your option
        Option "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" "25 25"
EndSection
```

When I run the command mentioned above, the noise cancellation values remain unchanged. How do I permanently store these changes?

EDIT:
Another observation. Switching off the touchpad using `xinput set-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics off" "1"`, does update the setting for off, but without any effect. Touchpad still responds and annoys the hell out of me.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following in the terminal:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

turns it off. Then to turn it on you turn the zero to 1.

You can then setup a bash script to toggle the touchpad on and off quickly.